# Batch script works in XP and not in Win7

Tags: windows, batch-file

Utilizing the knowledge of these forums, I compiled a useful batch script.

```
Del "- Output.tx_"
Del "- Output.txt"

FOR %%I in (*.txt) do @echo Filename: %%~nxI >>"- Output.tx_" & echo. >>"- Output.tx_" & echo. >>"- Output.tx_" & FOR %%f in (%%I) do type %%I >>"- Output.tx_" & echo. >>"- Output.tx_" & echo. >>"- Output.tx_"

TYPE "- Output.tx_" | MORE /E /P /S > "- Output.txt"
Del "- Output.tx_"
```

My home computer has XP (SP3, 32-bit), and the script combines the text files perfectly as shown below.

```
Filename: Test1.txt  

[Text file 1 contents]

Filename: Test2.txt  

[Text file 2 contents] 

... and so on.
```

However, I had run this script as a test on my computer at work a few months ago and ran into problems.  The computer at work has Windows 7 (32-bit, SP1) and combined only the text files' titles into the output file.  This resulted in the following:

```
Filename: Test1.txt  

Filename: Test2.txt     

... and so on.
```

Any comments or feedback in getting the script to work properly on Windows 7 would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

DWIC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that some (or all) of your text files on your Win7 computer have spaces or special characters in there names, such that TYPE is not able to find them. There should be an error message if this happens, but it is not in your output file because you haven't redirected stderr.

The problem can be solved by quoting the variable.

Your code is more complicated than it needs to be. Here is a simplified version that does the same thing, except the quoting problem has been fixed. I also redirected stderr.

```
@echo off
2>nul del "- Output.txt"
(
  for %%F in (*.txt) do @(
    echo Filename: %%F
    echo.
    echo.
    type "%%F"
    echo.
    echo.
  )
) | more /s /p >"- Output.tx_" 2>&1
move "- Output.tx_" "- Output.txt" >nul
```

Comment: EDIT - Added discussion about errors, and redirected stderr in code.

Comment: You sir, are correct!  Thank you! The files at work have spaces in their titles, whereas my test files at home did not.  Thus, I am able to replicate the error on my home computer, which of course means that it is not a problem with Windows 7 after all.  

Although, I am having some problems with your script and can't seem to iron them out on my own.  Unless I remove the "&>1" at the end, the script doesn't work.  And after I do so, I end up with the following for my output.

Comment: `C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\Macro (misc) projects\BAT\Test Folder>(echo Filename: - Output.txt   & echo.   & echo.   & type "- Output.txt"   & echo.   & echo.  ) 

Filename: - Output.txt  
    
C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\Macro (misc) projects\BAT\Test Folder>(echo Filename: Test 1.txt   & echo.   & echo.   & type "Test 1.txt"   & echo.   & echo.  )  

Filename: Test 1.txt  
    
[Text file 1 contents]   
  
... and so on.`

Comment: If you wouldn't mind helping me once more... I'm curious if it is possible to not have the extra lines that contain the filepaths?  

I understand you're busy with other projects so I'll go ahead and mark the question as having been answered. 

Thanks again, 

DWIC

Comment: @DWICBIOOM - My previous edit intended to redirect stdout to stdin, but I forgot the `2` before `>&1`. I missed the intent of your .tx_ file when I originally looked at your code, I reinstated it to avoid including the output file in the output. Lastly I had a problem with ECHO being enabled within the left side of the pipe because of how pipes work. All has been fixed in the code in my answer.

Comment: Your updated script works perfectly, thank you yet again.  Also, I have seen some of your posts on stack exchange as well as another forum (dostips).  I see that you're very active in helping the programming community overcome complex problems and guiding noobs such as myself.  I expect there a ton of others, who are just as grateful for receiving your help as I am. Thanks again, DWIC